# Monotouch memory limitation crash

Tags: ipad, memory, xamarin.ios, crash

I have a question about monotouch app memory limitation.

I tried to stress my iPad memory with a very simple app that allocates 1MB arrays into a list. On each loop I display the number of loop. I notice my app crashing around 130 MB allocation.

My code:

```cs
List<byte[]> arrays = new List<byte[]>();
try
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1323; i++)
    {
        arrays.Add(new byte[1024 * 1024]);
        Console.WriteLine("RAM: " + (i + 1) + " Mo");
    }
}
catch { }
```

I don't understand why, on an iPad 3 or iPad 4, my app crashes around 130MB with following message:

> Native stacktrace:
>
> ```
> 0   TestMemory                          0x002687f9 mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 244
> 1   TestMemory                          0x00295d75 sigabrt_signal_handler + 112
> 2   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x35a75e93 _sigtramp + 42
> 3   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x35a6c123 pthread_kill + 58
> 4   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x35aa8973 abort + 94
> 5   TestMemory                          0x0026353d GC_expand_hp_inner + 0
> 6   TestMemory                          0x00263637 GC_expand_hp_inner + 250
> 7   TestMemory                          0x00263aed GC_collect_or_expand + 128
> 8   TestMemory                          0x00265d99 GC_alloc_large + 96
> 9   TestMemory                          0x00265fe9 GC_generic_malloc + 180
> 10  TestMemory                          0x00266185 GC_malloc_atomic + 112
> 11  TestMemory                          0x0028c011 mono_array_new_specific + 124
> 12  TestMemory                          0x00172e04 wrapper_managed_to_native_object___icall_wrapper_mono_array_new_specific_intptr_int + 68
> 13  TestMemory                          0x0007305c MonoTouch_UIKit_UIControlEventProxy_Activated + 68
> 14  TestMemory                          0x0016df50 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 200
> 15  TestMemory                          0x002314e3 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 1054
> 16  TestMemory                          0x0028c8c3 mono_runtime_invoke + 90
> 17  TestMemory                          0x0022b6f7 native_to_managed_trampoline_MonoTouch_UIKit_UIControlEventProxy_Activated + 178
> 18  UIKit                               0x3ace40a5 <redacted> + 72
> 19  UIKit                               0x3ace4057 <redacted> + 30
> 20  UIKit                               0x3ace4035 <redacted> + 44
> 21  UIKit                               0x3ace38eb <redacted> + 502
> 22  UIKit                               0x3ace357b <redacted> + 242
> 23  UIKit                               0x3ac0c523 <redacted> + 318
> 24  UIKit                               0x3abf9801 <redacted> + 380
> 25  UIKit                               0x3abf911b <redacted> + 6154
> 26  GraphicsServices                    0x3637c5a3 <redacted> + 590
> 27  GraphicsServices                    0x3637c1d3 <redacted> + 34
> 28  CoreFoundation                      0x38856173 <redacted> + 34
> 29  CoreFoundation                      0x38856117 <redacted> + 138
> 30  CoreFoundation                      0x38854f99 <redacted> + 1384
> 31  CoreFoundation                      0x387c7ebd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
> 32  CoreFoundation                      0x387c7d49 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
> 33  GraphicsServices                    0x3637b2eb GSEventRunModal + 74
> 34  UIKit                               0x3ac4d2f9 UIApplicationMain + 1120
> 35  TestMemory                          0x0008b3c4 wrapper_managed_to_native_MonoTouch_UIKit_UIApplication_UIApplicationMain_int_string___intptr_intptr + 240
> 36  TestMemory                          0x00219bf0 TestMemory_Application_Main_string__ + 152
> 37  TestMemory                          0x0016df50 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 200
> 38  TestMemory                          0x002314e3 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 1054
> 39  TestMemory                          0x0028c8c3 mono_runtime_invoke + 90
> 40  TestMemory                          0x0028f3a7 mono_runtime_exec_main + 306
> 41  TestMemory                          0x0029262b mono_runtime_run_main + 482
> 42  TestMemory                          0x00242ecf mono_jit_exec + 94
> 43  TestMemory                          0x002cce3c main + 2220
> 44  TestMemory                          0x00002028 start + 40
> ```

Comment: See crash log using `Xcode Organizer`. If you see fields `Free pages`, `Wired pages`, `Purgeable pages` and `Largest process`, it's a memory warning: no more memory available for app. BTW, 128 mb is application memory limit in iOS.

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228389%28v=vs.80%29.aspx, `Once declared, you allocate memory to the array`. So your case is exactly excessive memory consumption.

Answer (score 2):

You crash because you use up all the memory iOS is willing to give you. This is not a MonoTouch limitation, it's an iOS limitation.

Comment: Hi rolf and thanks for your anwser. Do you know why if i try to allocated 4Mb block (arrays.Add(new byte[4096* 1024]);) I achieve to grow until 320 MB allocation before my app crash and I pass in the callback fucntion DidReceiveMemoryWarning whereas when I make allocation by 1MB block I crash without pass into it.

Comment: Apple doesn't guarantee that DidReceiveMemoryWarning is called. The problem can also be that you're hitting an iOS limitation on the number of allocations, not the sum of the size of them (it crashes after 130 memory allocations). Note that for smaller object, Mono will request memory in chunks, not once per object, so this is usually not a problem.